# Regular neighborhoud of a surface with boundary

Tags: solution-verification, geometric-topology

It is obvious that the product of a 2-disk with $n$ holes with the unit interval is a handlebody of genus $n$. I have read that this generalizes to the product of an (orientable) surface of genus $g$ with $n$ holes is a handlebody of genus $2g + n - 1$. I'm trying to visualize this but so far I'm failing. Can you please help me?

PS. I know there is a question here that is pretty much exactly like what I'm asking but I can't quite understand the answer there. Also I'm interested in more of a geometric understanding of the fact.

EDIT. Can someone please verify if my thinking is correct? Let $S_g^n$ be an orientable surface of genus $g$ and with $n$ boundary components, i.e. $S_g^n$ is a sphere with $g$ handles and $n$ holes. Then the $3$-manifold $M=S_g^n \times [0,1]$ has boundary that is two disjoint copies of $S_g^n$ with $n$ hollow tubes connecting the boundary components of the copies of $S_g^n$. By thinking of one of the tubes as being the the tube that connects the two $S_g^n$ into one connected sum, we lose one tube and what we have is a sphere with $2g+n-1$ handles. But that is the boundary of $M$ and therefore $M$ is a handlebody of said genus.

Comment: Which is the question that is "pretty much exactly like what you are asking"?

Comment: @M.Winter https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024876/surface-with-boundary-cross-an-interval-is-a-handlebody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is okay as far as identifying the surface that bounds $M$, but it does NOT follow that $M$ is a handlebody of the same genus. A fixed compact surface can be homeomorphic to the boundary of many different, non-homeomorphic 3-manifolds.

Let me explain a method which works in general by first specializing to the surface $S^1_g$, the one-holed torus. Define an *essential arc* to be an embedded arc which intersects the boundary solely in its endpoints, and which is not homotopic rel endpoints into the boundary. Two essential arcs are *equivalent* if they are homotopic by a homotopy which keeps the endpoints in the boundary.

You can choose two inequivalent essential arcs $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \subset S^1_g$ such that when you cut along $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ the result is a disc. To see this, start with the standard square gluing diagram for a torus, and then remove a small quarter-circle neighborhood of each vertex of the square. Now consider $S^1_g \times [0,1]$. Each of $\alpha_i \times [0,1]$ is a properly embedded disc. When you cut open along these 2 discs, what's left is a single 3-ball. Therefore, $S^1_g \times [0,1]$ is handlebody of genus $2$.

In general, using that $\chi(S^n_g) = 2-2g-n$, you can cut $S^n_g$ along a non-separating set of $2g+n-1$ pairwise inequivalent essential arcs $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{2g+n-1}$ so that what's left is simply connected. In $S^n_g \times [0,1]$, each of $\alpha_i \times [0,1]$ is a properly embedded disc. When you cut $S^n_g \times [0,1]$ along these $2g+n-1$ discs, what's left is a single 3-ball. Therefore $S^n_g \times [0,1]$ is a handlebody of genus $2g+n-1$.

Comment: Yes you are right of course otherwise every knot complement would be a torus and all knots would be equivalent. Thank you once again. I will study your answer and see if I can follow it. Is there any particular literature where I can study similar methods?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make the connection between the euler characteristic and the number of essential arcs. I can find the essential arcs on the torus square following your advice for more than one holes as well, but I can't generalize it on the $2g$-polygon with more than one hole for $S_g$.

Comment: Nevermind, everything is ok. Thank you again.